# ejb get currently executing bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss5.x, ejb-2.x

I have several stateless beans and some service class that is called by that beans. I can not directly pass bean instance to that service class.

Are there any way to get currently executing bean instance? I just wonder if there any existing mechanism, so I will not need to write interceptors and related logic to save bean instance somewhere.

To be more specific:

```
public class MyBean implements MyBeanInterface, CommonBeanInterface {
     public void businessMethod() {
         SomeService service = ... // service is somehow obtained
         service.doWork();
     }
}

public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
     public void doWork() {
          CommonBeanInterface currentBean = getCurrentBean(); // its implementation I need
     }
}
```

So in service class I need to get bean instance that called this service.

Any information would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an API to identify the bean that called that service. Note though that if the service is in the same container as the bean (i.e. there is no remote call involved) they will execute on the same thread. So you could use ThreadLocal to pass some information along.

Comment: Yes, `ThreadLocal` is what I wanted to use, but thought there is an existing API